# The static page works, but when put into PHP, CSS isn't rendered properly

Tags: php, html, css

I have the following code in a HTML file. This creates a styled list.

```
<style>
/* LIST #8 */
#list8 {  }
#list8 ul { list-style:none; }
#list8 ul li { font-family:Georgia,serif,Times; font-size:18px; }
#list8 ul li a { display:block; width:300px; height:28px; background-color:#333; border-left:5px solid #222; border-right:5px solid #222; padding-left:10px;
  text-decoration:none; color:#bfe1f1; }
#list8 ul li a:hover {  -moz-transform:rotate(-5deg); -moz-box-shadow:10px 10px 20px #000000;
  -webkit-transform:rotate(-5deg); -webkit-box-shadow:10px 10px 20px #000000;
  transform:rotate(-5deg); box-shadow:10px 10px 20px #000000; }
</style>
<div id="list8">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#">9th Fall 2017</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">10th Spring 2018</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

This is how the HTML file renders.

[image]

I have the following PHP file.

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password", "Booking_Databse");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT SemesterName FROM Semester_tbl";

if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
?>
<style>
/* LIST #8 */
#list8 {  }
#list8 ul { list-style:none; }
#list8 ul li { font-family:Georgia,serif,Times; font-size:18px; }
#list8 ul li a { display:block; width:300px; height:28px; background-color:#333; border-left:5px solid #222; border-right:5px solid #222; padding-left:10px;
  text-decoration:none; color:#bfe1f1; }
#list8 ul li a:hover {  -moz-transform:rotate(-5deg); -moz-box-shadow:10px 10px 20px #000000;
  -webkit-transform:rotate(-5deg); -webkit-box-shadow:10px 10px 20px #000000;
  transform:rotate(-5deg); box-shadow:10px 10px 20px #000000; }
</style>
<div id="list8">
   <ul>
  </ul><?php
    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
      echo '<li><a href="#">' . $row[0] . '</a></li>';

    }
  ?>
     </ul>
</div>
  <?php

    /* free result set */
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

This is how the PHP file renders:

[image]

I want the PHP file to render like the HTML file. I do not know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You close your `<ul>` before doing the loop...

See:

```
<div id="list8">
   <ul>
  </ul><?php
    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
      echo '<li><a href="#">' . $row[0] . '</a></li>';

    }
  ?>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Change to:

```
<div id="list8">
   <ul>
    <?php
    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
      echo '<li><a href="#">' . $row[0] . '</a></li>';

    }
  ?>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You close the `</ul>` before the loop

```
</ul><?php // <-------------------------------  This </ul> shouldn't be here
/* fetch associative array */
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
  echo '<li><a href="#">' . $row[0] . '</a></li>';

}
?>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<div id="list8">
   <ul>
  <?php
    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
      echo '<li><a href="#">' . $row[0] . '</a></li>';

    }
  ?>
     </ul>
</div>
```